# Clamav-Daemon Does Not Write Pidfile

Tags: debian, pid, clamav

I am trying to configure Monit to monitor clamav-daemon.  However, it appears that the `/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon` script does NOT actually write the pdifile to `/var/run/clamav`

```
/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon:   
    NAME="clamd"
    DESC="ClamAV daemon"
    CLAMAVCONF=/etc/clamav/clamd.conf
    SUPERVISOR=/usr/bin/daemon
    SUPERVISORNAME=daemon
    SUPERVISORPIDFILE="/var/run/clamav/daemon-clamd.pid"
    SUPERVISORARGS="--name=$NAME --respawn $DAEMON -F $SUPERVISORPIDFILE"
    DATABASEDIR="/var/lib/clamav"
```

Currently, my `/var/run/clamav` directory only has `clamd.ctl`

I have no warnings when I run `systemctl clamav-daemon status` and all other functionality of clamav-daemon seem to be intact (email / upload scanning etc.)

How can I enable `/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon`  to write the missing pidfile?

Answer (score 0):

I welcome others to post answers to the above question, but in the meanwhile I found an effective workaround.

`nano /etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service.d/extend.conf`

add:

```
[service]  
Restart=always
```